# error when running anonymous block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

running into the below error when trying to run a simple anonymous block

```
   do $$ begin raise notice 'Hello, World!'; end $$;
```

error

> Describe Error: Failed to retrieve EXPLAIN plan(s): ERROR: syntax
>   error at or near "do"

DB is PostgreSQL 9.1.18 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
any ideas on what is going wrong?

I am using aqua data studio and pgadmin and get the same error

Comment: And what is the error? And why are you using an unsupported and unmaintained version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I thought I initially out the error in there

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what is an supported /un maintained? the database is a vendors recent deployment im just trying to create reporting around the data

Comment: The command is ok. The error message means that you've tried to `EXPLAIN` it, what is impossible in the case of a `DO` block.